# Mocking dot notation React components in Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a component that, depending on data being loaded, renders either a component or a loading component:

```
// components/example

import Component from 'components/component';


const Example = ({loaded}) => (
  <>
    {loaded ? <Component/> : <Component.Loading/>}
  </>
)
```

The loading component is written as dot notation, because I feel like it makes it easier to read and use.
Is there any way to mock `<Component.Loading/>` in my unit tests?

This was my best guess, but it didn't work:

```
// components/example.test

import Example from './example'

const mockedComponent = jest.fn();

jest.mock('components/component', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  default: () => mockedComponent(),
}));

const setup = () => {
  const utils = render(<Example loading={false} />);
  return {
    ...utils,
  };
};

it('Renders correctly', () => {
    const component = () => <>Main component</>;
    component.Loading = () => <>Loading component</>;
    mockedComponent.mockReturnValue(component);
    setup();  
});
```

Jest doesn't like this, and tells me that `<Component.Loading/>` is undefined.

```
  console.error
    Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

Comment: Your test double has to have the same interface as the thing it's replacing. If your real component has a Loading property which is also a component, why is your test double just `() => <>Mocked component</>`?

Comment: Well that's the question, I don't know how to write it so that it will work in Jest .

Comment: It doesn't really matter that it's _"in Jest"_, is the point. The rigging is Jest-specific, but once you get down to the `default` it's just a _value_ that's standing in for the real component. Presumably you know how to write a component with a property, so why not do that when creating a test double?

Comment: I did, but it didn't work. Added my code to the OP.

Comment: Please provide a [mre], not just _"didn't work"_.

Comment: As I said, I already added it to the OP.

Comment: I can see that, but you just say _"it didn't work"_, rather than illustrating what _did_ happen. One obvious thing is that the value of `default` should be _the component_, not a function returning the component (unless that's your real implementation, and we don't know because you don't show it, but that seems unlikely).

Comment: Added to the OP.

Comment: That is my implementation, any other way I tried it gave me compile errors. I understand how to mock in Jest, but I do not understand how to mock dot notation components in Jest. That's why I asked the question :/

Comment: Again, _"in Jest"_ isn't relevant. `jest.mock('components/component', () => ({ __esModule: true, default: testDouble }));`, which is fine, is the Jest-specific part, but neither `() => <>Mocked component</>` nor `() => mockedComponent()` is a _"dot notation component"_.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately if I do `default: testDouble` I get a hoisting error: `Cannot access 'mockedComponent' before initialization`. Which is why it is not typed like that.

Comment: Even a trivial test double like `const Dummy = () => null; Dummy.Loading = () => "loading..."` seems to work for me, so again please give a MRE that helps recreate the specific problem you're having.

Comment: Could you share your code?

Comment: What I just posted _is_ the code, that's the whole test double. But that's not the way around this works; you're supposed to give something that _doesn't_ work, and that we can run locally to prove that, along with the specific outputs from e.g. running Jest. I had to guess parts of the two files you did post and invent the third (equivalent `components/component`) entirely.

Comment: Your example is the same as what I have, which is obviously not working. I've added the whole code to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Right so this while doing this I was going off how you *usually* mock react components:

```
jest.mock('component/something', () => ({
 __esModule: true,
  default: () => <>Mocked component</>,
}));
```

This usually works, but for dot-notation component the syntax is different:

```
const component = () => <>Main component</>;
component.Loading = () => <>Loading</>;

jest.mock('components/component', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  default: component,
}));
```

If you want to go a step further you can mock with a `jest.fn()`:

```
const mockedItemStatus = jest.fn();
const mockedItemStatusSkeleton = jest.fn();

const component = () => mockedItemStatus();
component.Loading = () => mockedItemStatusSkeleton();

jest.mock('components/component', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  default: component,
}));
```

Then in your tests you can make the mock return the specific component you need:

```
  it('Renders correctly', () => {
    mockedItemStatusSkeleton.mockImplementation(() => <>Loading</>);
    render(<Component/>)
    expect(mockedItemStatusSkeleton).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

Comment: Note that `() => mockedItemStatus()` can just be... `mockedItemStatus`. Also I'd argue that `expect(mockedItemStatusSkeleton).toHaveBeenCalled()` isn't a good assertion - what you care about is _what gets rendered_, not the mechanism by which that happens. With the Dummy I proposed above, for example, you'd assert on `loading...` being displayed.

Comment: It can't, as previously said Jest does not run tests because `mockedItemStatus` is not initialised. Thanks.

Comment: _That_ is something worth asking about. This is why I kept asking for a MRE, because these details matter - when I used `Dummy` it worked. This is because Jest handles variables prefixed with `mock...` in a slightly different way: https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks#calling-jestmock-with-the-module-factory-parameter. Given that the test double is only used when the component gets _rendered_, not on module load, it's safe despite the hoisting.