# Mocking compound components with Jest

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

I have a compound component that looks like this:

```js
export const Layout = Object.assign(Main, {
    Top, Content, Center, Left, Right,
})
```

There is an object assigning `Main` to some other components so can use dot notation. Below you can see how I am trying to mock it inside the `jest.setup.js` file:

```js
jest.mock(
    '~/layouts/Layout', () => ({
        __esModule: true,
        default: (props) => {
            return <mock-layout>{props.children}</mock-layout>
        },
    }),
)
```

Running `jest --ci` will return an error with the message `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Top')`

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71558903/mocking-dot-notation-react-components-in-jest) topic I found a way to do something like this:

```js
const component = (props) => <layout-mock>{props.children}</layout-mock>;
component.Top = (props) => <layout-mock-top>{props.children}</layout-mock-top>;

jest.mock(
    '~/layouts/Layout', () => ({
        __esModule: true,
        default: component,
    }),
)
```

But it gives me the same error.
How could I mock it properly? Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to update the variable name to mockVariable for this to work in order to work around the out of scope variables error.
Details here: https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks#calling-jestmock-with-the-module-factory-parameter